# Disabling serving PHP files from a folder in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a directory on server, from which I only want .JPG files to be served by apache - and apache should deny requests for php, php3, php5 etc files.

What should I write in .htaccess?

I have tried following, first two are giving 500 internal error, third one is not working at all!

```
 <Directory full-path-to/USERS>
 <FilesMatch "\.(php3?|phtml)$">  
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
 </FilesMatch>
```

```
<LocationMatch "/USERS/.*\.(php3?|phtml)$">
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
</LocationMatch>


php_flag engine off
```

Regards,

Comment: if you check error_log, you should see more detailed messages associated with your HTTP 500s.

And of course, the simplest solution would be to simply store the jpegs in a different folder...

Comment: Thanks Frank - I was about to open the log files; but then dave came up with a helping hand.. issue fixed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about some mod_rewrite?

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(\.jpg|\.jpeg)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```

This would allow only .jpg or .jpeg files to be served, and everything else would get a 403 forbidden.

Comment: +1 for an interresting solution.  What about side effects of having the RewriteEngine turned on?  (I don't know very much about it, that's why I'm asking.)

Comment: Glad it helped. I'm not sure what the side-effects would be, but I have a feeling it would be very small or non-existant.